# How to know whether a jsch session is down or not？

Tags: linux, session, ssh, jsch

I use the following code to get a jsch session：

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
String user = "test";
String host = "172.23.54.253";
String password = "paas@tju";
int port = 22;
Session session = jsch.getSession(user,host,port);
UserInfo userInfo = new MyUserInfo(null);
session.setUserInfo(userInfo);
session.setPassword(password);
session.connect();
```

About 3 hours later, I execute the following code:

```
if(session.isConnected())
{
    System.out.println("Session is still connected!");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Session is disconnected!);
}
```

I found that the jsch session is still connected! But when I check the /var/log/secure file, I found that the session has already been closed!
If I open a channel with the jsch session which is created 3 hours ago,
a JSchException would be thrown as below:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: session is down
at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.sendChannelOpen(Channel.java:762)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:151)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:145)
at com.inspur.jobSchedule.test.PressureTest.test(PressureTest.java:117)
at com.inspur.jobSchedule.test.PressureTest.main(PressureTest.java:138)
```

I known the keepalive time is 2 hours for a tcp connection on Linux. But why
when I call the "isConnected" method of the session,it returns true?

Comment: I used the JSch library in quite a few projects. My opinion about the library is that it does a great job at simple tasks, but it has quite a few rough edges. I have tried to hold a connection for a long time, but changed it to reconnect.

Comment: Thank you vary much @Leland Barton! After making many tries,  we hold a session 
for a long time  by invoking the following two methods  before invoking Session#connect.

    Session#setServerAliveCountMax(int count)
 Session#setServerAliveInterval(int milliseconds)
It should be noted that the 'timeout' field of a session is also set as the value of 
'serverAliveInterval' field, if you invoke the Session#setServerAliveInterval(int milliseconds).